# insertRowsAtIndexPaths in UITableView adding Duplicate Rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, swift2

I'm using the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` method to add new rows to my `UITableView`. There is a problem of duplicate rows being added.

For example, If I type `"HI"` and then touch return, a row with the text `"HI"` is added to the table. If I then go back and type `"Hello"` and press return, a row that says `"HI"` is added again. Here is some code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    sendMessage(textField.text)
    return true
}

func sendMessage(text:String){

    var message = Message(text: text)
    //global array that stores all the messages
    self.messages.append(message)

    let indexPathZero : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPathZero) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Thanks so much!

> **Edit**: Here's the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:GroupChatMessageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupChatMessageCell
    cell.message.text = messages[indexPath.row].text
    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1,-1);

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: @Larme check out my edit :)

Comment: If you printf `message.text` (in `sendMessage:`), do you have "Hello"? Could you also give the code of `numberOfRowInSection:` and `numberOfSection:`, just to be sure?

Comment: BTW, you can replace `let cell:GroupChatMessageCell` with `let cell` since you explicitly cast the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are appending new messages to the end of the array, but inserting new rows at the first row. So it asks for first array element in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Can be fixed by changing `self.messages.append(message)` to `self.messages.insert(message, atIndex: 0)`

Comment: I have the same problem as above and I already have messages.insert.  Can you look at this question and give me your opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884055/duplicating-last-row-of-table-when-new-value-entered?noredirect=1#comment98445118_55884055

Answer (score 0):

implement estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath do the trick !

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Enjoy ;)