# Duplicating last row of table when new value entered

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a chat feature within my app.  The page loads the existing data as an array called hhmessages. The last message in the conversation was 'Welcome', when I enter new text 'Thank You' and hit enter the table automatically displays 'Welcome' again instead of 'Thank You.'  If it exit out of the page and come back it now shows 'Thank You' as the last message.  It's working on the backend just the instant update isn't showing the value in the UITableView when entered.

This is for an iPhone app. 
UPDATED TO SHOW COMPLETE CODE - Now that reverse has been removed the new entry shows as blank.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

 extension String {

    // Calculeta the hight string Function
    func calculateTextFrameRect(
        objectsInPlaceHeight: CGFloat,
        objectsInPlaceWidth: CGFloat,
        fontSize: CGFloat,
        fontWeight: CGFloat) -> CGSize
    {
        let bounding = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - objectsInPlaceWidth, height: .infinity)
        let rect = NSString(string: self).boundingRect(
            with: bounding,
            options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin),
            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: fontWeight))],
            context: nil)
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: rect.height + objectsInPlaceHeight )
    }
}
// Messages for test
let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 375, height: 559))

class Message {
    let message: String
    var incoming: [Int]
    let image: UIImage
    var avas = UIImage()
    init(message: String, image: UIImage, incoming: Int, avas: UIImage) {
        self.message = message
        self.image = image
        self.incoming = [incoming]
        self.avas = avas
    }
}

class ConversationViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {
    //var user = NSDictionary()
    var messages = NSDictionary()
    //var guest = NSDictionary()

    @IBOutlet var senderLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var senderageLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var senderraceLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var sendergenderLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var sendercityLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var senderstateLbl: UILabel!
    // @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var hhmessages = [AnyObject]()
    //var messages: [Message] = []
    var pictures = [UIImage]()

    var avas = [UIImage]()
    var avaURL = [String]()
    var isLoading = false
    var skip = 0
    var limit = 50
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var incoming: [Int] = []
    var comments = [String]()
    var ids = [String]()


    //var isSent: String = ""
    var isPictureSelected = false
    //var currentUser_ava = [Any]()
    @IBOutlet var pictureImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var avaImg: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var viewprofile_btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var imgprofile_btn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var replyTxt: UITextView!

    //var replyTxt:UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var replyTxt_height: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var replyTxt_bottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var picSelect: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var replyBtn: UIButton!
    var puuid = String()
    var imageSelected = false
    var coolIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var commentsTextView_bottom_identity = CGFloat()


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    // Table View here + basic configuration

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi));

        // dynamic cell height
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200

        loadPosts()

        replyTxt.layer.cornerRadius = replyTxt.bounds.width / 50
        replyTxt.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        replyTxt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        replyTxt.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        let username = messages["sender"] as? String

        self.navigationItem.title = username

    }
    // pre last func
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // remove observers of notification when the viewController is left
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
           NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }


    // exec-d once notification is caught -> KeyboardWillShow
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

        // getting the size of the keyboard
        if let keyboard_size = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            // increasing the bottom constraint by the keyboard's height
            replyTxt_bottom.constant += keyboard_size.height

        }

        // updating the layout with animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }


    // exec-d once notification is caught -> KeyboardWillHide
    @objc func keyboardWillHide() {


        // updating the layout with animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //replyTxt().resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(false)

    }

    // TABLEVIEW

    // Number os cells
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return hhmessages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let colorSmoothGray = UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 229/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1)
        let colorBrandBlue = UIColor(red: 148 / 255, green: 33 / 255, blue: 147 / 255, alpha: 1)
        let pictureURL = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as? String

        print("test 1", pictureURL)

        // no picture in the post
        if pictureURL == nil || pictureURL == "" {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell

            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))

            // shortcuts
            let hhpost = hhmessages[indexPath.row]
            let text = hhpost["messagetext"] as? String

                cell.messageLbl.text = text
                cell.messageLbl.textAlignment = .right
                cell.messageLbl.backgroundColor = colorSmoothGray
                cell.messageLbl.textColor = .black
                cell.messageLbl.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
                cell.messageLbl.font?.withSize(25)
                cell.messageLbl.clipsToBounds = true
           cell.messageLbl.sizeToFit()
            pictures.append(UIImage())


            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PicCell", for: indexPath) as! PicConversationCell
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))

            let smimages = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["path"] as? UIImage

            cell.smavaImg.image = smimages

            for i in 0 ..< self.incoming.count {
                // Confiture the constraints for cell
                if self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 1 {
                    // Text
                   cell.messageLbl.textAlignment = .left
                    cell.messageLbl.backgroundColor = colorBrandBlue
                    cell.messageLbl.textColor = .white
                    cell.messageLbl.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
                    cell.messageLbl.font?.withSize(25)
                    cell.messageLbl.clipsToBounds = true

                    // Constraints
                   cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive = true
                    cell.rightBubbleConstraint.isActive = false
                    if cell.postpictureImg.image == nil {
                        cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .black
                        cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                    }
                    else {
                        cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .black
                        cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                    }

                }
                else if self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 0 {
                    // Text
                    cell.messageLbl.textAlignment = .right
                    cell.messageLbl.backgroundColor = colorSmoothGray
                    cell.messageLbl.textColor = .black
                    cell.messageLbl.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
                    cell.messageLbl.font?.withSize(25)
                    cell.messageLbl.clipsToBounds = true

                    // Constraints
                    cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive = false
                    cell.rightBubbleConstraint.isActive = true
                    if cell.postpictureImg.image == nil {
                        cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .black
                        cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                    }
                    else {
                        cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .black
                        cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                    }

                }

           if cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive == true {


            cell.lefImageConstraint.isActive = true
                cell.rightImageConstraint.isActive = false

            } else {



                cell.lefImageConstraint.isActive = false
                cell.rightImageConstraint.isActive = true
            }


                let pictureString = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as! String
                let pictureURL = URL(string: pictureString)!

                // if there are still pictures to be loaded
                if hhmessages.count != pictures.count {

                    URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: pictureURL) { (data, response, error) in


                        // downloaded
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {

                            self.pictures.append(image)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                cell.postpictureImg.image = image
                            }
                        }

                        }.resume()

                    // cached picture
                } else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.postpictureImg.image = self.pictures[indexPath.row]
                    }
                }


            }
            return cell

        }

    }



    // pre load func
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    }

    // func of loading posts from server
    @objc func loadPosts() {
        //isLoading = true
        let me = user!["username"] as! String
        let meid = user!["id"] as! String
        print(meid)
        print(me)
        //print(username)
        let uuid = messages["uuid"] as! String
        print(uuid)

        // accessing php file via url path
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/message.php")!

        // pass information to php file
        let body = "username=\(me)&uuid=\(uuid)&recipient_id=\(meid)"
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi));

        // launch session
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // no error of accessing php file
                // error occured
                if error != nil {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    //self.isLoading = false
                    return
                }

                do {
                    // access data - safe mode
                    guard let data = data else {
                        Helper().showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                        //self.isLoading = false
                        return
                    }
                    // getting content of $returnArray variable of php file
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    // accessing json data - safe mode
                    guard let posts = json?["messages"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
                        //self.isLoading = false
                        return
                    }

                    // assigning all successfully loaded posts to our Class Var - posts (after it got loaded successfully)
                    self.hhmessages = posts

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    // scroll to the latest index (latest cell -> bottom)
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                  //  self.isLoading = false

                } catch {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    //self.isLoading = false
                    return
                }

            }
            }.resume()

    }

        @IBAction func viewprofile_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        // performSegue(withIdentifier: "guest2", sender: self.guest)

    }
    @IBAction func imgprofile_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        // performSegue(withIdentifier: "guest2", sender: self.guest)

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "guest" {

            if let destination = segue.destination as? GuestViewController {
                destination.guest = messages
            }
        }
    }

    // function sending requset to PHP to uplaod a file
    func uploadPost() {
        // validating vars before sending to the server
        guard let user_id = user?["id"] as? String, let username = user?["username"] as? String, let avaPath = user?["ava"] else {

            // converting url string to the valid URL
            if let url = URL(string: user?["ava"] as! String) {

                // downloading all data from the URL
                guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                    return
                }

                // converting donwloaded data to the image
                guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    return
                }

                // assigning image to the global var
                let currentUser_ava = image
            }

            return
        }

        let user_id_int = Int(user_id)!
        let messagetext = replyTxt.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        hhmessages.insert(messagetext as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi));
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

        replyTxt.text = ""
        textViewDidChange(replyTxt)
        let recipient = messages["username"] as! String
        let rid = String(describing: messages["recipient_id"]!)
        let uuid = messages["uuid"] as! String
        puuid = UUID().uuidString

        // prepare request
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/messagepost.php")!
        let body = "sender_id=\(user_id)&sender=\(username)&text=\(messagetext)&recipient_id=\(rid)&recipient=\(recipient)&uuid=\(uuid)&puuid=\(puuid)"

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

        // send request
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // error happened
                if error != nil {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    // converting received data from the server into json format
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                    // safe mode of casting json
                    guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                        return
                    }

                    // if the status of JSON is 200 - success
                    if parsedJSON["status"] as! String == "200" {

                    } else {
                        Helper().showAlert(title: "400", message: parsedJSON["status"] as! String, in: self)
                        return
                    }

                    // json error
                } catch {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

            }
            }.resume()

    }
    // exec-d whenever delegated textView has been changed by chars
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        // declaring new size of the textView. we increase the height
        let new_size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

        // assign new size to the textView
        textView.frame.size = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(fmaxf(Float(new_size.width), Float(textView.frame.width))), height: new_size.height)

        //UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        //}

    }

    @IBAction func picSelect_clicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // calling picker for selecting iamge
       showActionSheet()
    }
    // this function launches Action Sheet for the photos
    func showActionSheet() {

        // declaring action sheet
        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // declaring camera button
        let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in

            // if camera available on device, than show
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                self.showPicker(with: .camera)
            }

        }

        // declaring library button
        let library = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in

            // checking availability of photo library
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
                self.showPicker(with: .photoLibrary)
            }

        }

        // declaring cancel button
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        // adding buttons to the sheet
        sheet.addAction(camera)
        sheet.addAction(library)
        sheet.addAction(cancel)

        // present action sheet to the user finally
        self.present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    // takes us to the PickerController (Controller that allows us to select picture)
    func showPicker(with source: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = source
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    // executed whenever the image has been picked via pickerController
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        // accessing selected image
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage

        // assigning selected image to pictureImageView
        pictureImg.image = image

        // cast boolean as TRUE -> Picture Is Selected
        isPictureSelected = true

        // remove pickerController

        pictureImg.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        // cast as a true to save image file in server
        if pictureImg.image == info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            imageSelected = true
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // exec when pictureImageView has been tapped
    @IBAction func pictureImageView_tapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // declaring action sheet
        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // declaring delete button
        let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in
            self.pictureImg.image = UIImage()
        }

        // declaring cancel button
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        // adding buttons to the sheet
        sheet.addAction(delete)
        sheet.addAction(cancel)

        // present action sheet to the user finally
        self.present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    // custom body of HTTP request to upload image file
    func createBodyWithParams(_ parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: Data, boundary: String) -> Data {

        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }


        // if file is not selected, it will not upload a file to server, because we did not declare a name file
        var filename = ""

        if imageSelected == true {
            filename = "notes-\(puuid).jpg"
        }


        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey)
        body.appendString("\r\n")

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body as Data

    }



    @IBAction func replyBtn_clicked(_ sender: Any) {

        if replyTxt.text.isEmpty == false && replyTxt.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty == false {
            uploadPost()
            //tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }



    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {

        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let curFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let targetFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = targetFrame.origin.y - curFrame.origin.y
        //print("deltaY",deltaY)

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.replyTxt.frame.origin.y+=deltaY // Here You Can Change UIView To UITextField
            self.tableView.frame.origin.y+=deltaY // Here You Can Change UIView To UITextField
            self.replyBtn.frame.origin.y+=deltaY // Here You Can Change UIView To UITextField
            self.picSelect.frame.origin.y+=deltaY // Here You Can Change UIView To UITextField

        },completion: nil)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ replyTxt: UITextField) -> Bool {
        replyTxt.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your code for numberOfRows function ?

Comment: @MaryamFekri just updated to show numberOfRows:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hhmessages.count
    }

Comment: I think if you scroll the table entirely in a way that tableView call the cellForRow for all the rows again, it will fix your rows. but for sure that's not the solution I just want to know if this is the state Im thinking of

Comment: I would suggest first comment this line :     tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true) 
I have a feeling that this one will again call your cellForRow function and since you have added the text to your array then it will show again as the last row

Comment: you can also make a breakpoint in cellForRow function and check how many times it gets called after which line of code

Comment: Thanks @MaryamFekri. I tried commenting out the tableView.scrollToRow but it didn't work.  It didn't show another row as inserted in the UI but when I re-entered the page that new value was there.  Basically the animation was there with the new value that was entered in the textfield .

Comment: I tried the breakpoint but I struggle reading them.  I can never tell what to look for.

Comment: would you be able to share the whole viewController somehow in a repository or something ?

Comment: I've uploaded with the complete viewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are inserting the new text at

`let indexPath = IndexPath(row: hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0)`

which is the last field of the array. 
but in your cellForRow: you have

`let text = hhmessages.reversed()[indexPath.row]["messagetext"] as! String`

which shows the first field of your array in the last cell of tableView.

I think thats your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Maryam, unfortunately I've tried different variations of your recommendation but no luck.  I'll post my entire view controller as requested.

Comment: Hi @Maryam, I removed the reverse and changed some other code but now it's showing a blank instead of repeating the last row.

Comment: I cant tell you whats wrong until I see your code. you should trace your code and see how many rows you want on each step and whats your array.count on each step and if everything matches then you need to check your array of strings to see if its in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have told, you are messing up your order in hhmessages.
Imagine you have messages `Welcome`, `Hello`, and you are trying to add `Thank Your`, your code with more comments:

```
 self.hhmessages.insert(messagetext as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex) // Thank You is inserted to the end of the array at 3rd position (2)

 let indexPath = IndexPath(row: hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0) // ok, let's get index of 3rd row (2)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) // add new row to the end
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Then later UIKit asks you to load this new 3rd row at position 2, and you call:

```
   let text = hhmessages.reversed()[indexPath.row]["messagetext"] as! String
```

The problem is `hhmessages.reversed()` which reverses your array, and makes `Thank you` in fact first at position 0, and `Welcome` the last one at position 2, which will get the text `Welcome`.
The second problem I see is this line:

```
let pictureURL = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as? String
```

Here you are getting unreveresed picture url, which at least is very strange.

Comment: Thanks @KleMix, I tried removing reverse and nothing happened.  I have reverse in there so my table will load from the bottom

Comment: I removed the reverse and changed some other code but now it's showing a blank instead of repeating the last row